Fantasy movie / tv-series in the 90s with a female lead and an evil queen
The movie (or mini-series) I am looking for played in the 90s on German television, though I don’t know if it was necessarily German. It could have been English and dubbed for example. 
I don’t remember much, but somehow the couple of scenes I do remember stick with me. 
It was a fantasy with real people and real costumes etc. The lead was a woman with short black hair, and I think she used a sword. The antagonist was an evil queen. 
This evil queen had slaves, people in a mushroom-like costume, and in one particular scene she fed them to some kind of evil ghosts – this haunted me quite a bit as a kid.  
In one of the final scenes a woman sacrificed herself for the protagonist and her friends, by placing herself in some kind of iron door that snapped. 
I just can’t remember if it was the evil queen that turned good in her final moments, or just another female character that gave her life.
Another minor flashback that I can remember was the female lead walking in a mushroom village, with mushrooms as large as houses (No, I am not talking about those little blue fellas...). 
I apologize for not giving that much info. I just don’t remember anything else.

I think you are looking for the Fantaghirò series / Prinzessin Fantaghirò in German
Especially the second movie: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103409/
The princess and the black witch (played by Brigitte Nielsen):

Some of the mushroom gnomes:

Some plot details: 

He sets out with his army, leaving behind Fantaghirò, who has sworn not to lift another weapon for the rest of her life. However, Fantaghirò finds that she has to break her promise, and secretly sets out on her own to the Dark Kingdom, where she learns that the Black Witch's plan is much more sinister.

Here is a German trailer, some mushrooms can be seen around 0:34: 



@Jack That's great, but don't forget to approve the answer (by clicking on the check mark next to it).
