Fantasy movie about two worlds (one is real, an one is from the book read by a kid) with a horse turning to ice, and a dragon freezing someone
There was a movie made in 2000s, maybe before, and I remember few scenes: 

There was a man with his horse. The horse drinks a little water from a fountain and it turned into ice. But a little boy in the real world was reading all that in his book.
The main protagonist (whose horse turned to ice) jumps to the real world and in that action he breaks a stack of books (from bottom to top).
Also when he gets to the fountain and horse takes a sip, the kid who is reading the book can see that scene in the book, but when he turned the page there was the same page beneath, so when the horse was freezing, the boy kept turning pages but every last one was the same.
Next there was a man in a little wooden house and he and his group found a secret chest in the hole in the floor, but he assumed there will be a trap and he tied up that chest and lift it, and then spikes got out all over the floor.
Next he and his group are outside that house and a big dragon came there and he was spitting ice, and he froze one member of the group.

I think there was also a main antagonist, a women, she had a ring with green particles and light surrounding it.

Sounds like it could be one of the Neverending Story films (dreadful perversions of an utterly fantastic novel). Does any of this sound familiar?

All 3 Neverending Story movies were released before 2000, though.

Neverending story seems very familiar, but not a single scene i stated above is not shoved on trailer or other videos on youtube (besides a kid reading a book).

Animated, fully or partially or fully live action?

The only Neverending Story with a female antagonist is #2 and none of the scenes you mention sound familiar (there's a guy with a horse but it doesn't freeze; there's a dragon but it breathes fire, Bastian doesn't really read the book much in #2, etc.)

It was a live action movie, something like this answer: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45834/fantasy-movie-tv-series-in-the-90s-with-a-female-lead-and-an-evil-queen   But i dont recall a woman being protagonist. And it reminds a little like The 10th kingdom, but i watched 10th kingdom and it is not, but similar style

Maybe   Dragonheart: A New Beginning  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NghvaMdUbVY ?

It's a one season-only TV series Tales from the Neverending Story (2001), loosely based on Michael Ende's novel The Neverending Story.

In the novel and films, it is Bastian who enters the world of
  Fantasia, but here it is Atreyu who enters our world. The series also
  introduces new supporting characters.

Wikipedia
IMDB

Clip frozen horse

@Danny Kindly merge both of your account by mentioned method, so that you can easily manage them too and remember to accept and upvote Marry's answer if it's right.
